# Create a wave border-bottom line

Tags: css

I am to make a wave styled `border-bottom:1px solid;` rather than a straight line. How can this be accomplished?

So `border-bottom` looks like:

[image]

And I want something like:

[image]

What is the best way to achieve this? Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8y50bb1b/).

Comment: Background image, border image...

Comment: @Shomz Yes, I know I can simply add a background image, but that will add another request to the browser, I am looking for a solution without an image.

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: you could draw it with svg or canvas.

Comment: If you don't want a server request, you can hard-code the base64 image code and use that... it's a small image, shouldn't look too bad.

Comment: @DanielA.White Could you kindly demonstrate how to draw this with svg or convas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) or [border image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image), and since you want to avoid an additional server request, you can embed the base64 data for the image:

```css
div {height: 100px; background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) center bottom repeat-x}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

(obviously, the image needs trimming/fixing, but you get the idea)

I think this solution will be **much** easier than trying to build something like that using CSS.

Comment: This is actually very nice, I was not aware of the base64 solution, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, actually, the base64 string turned out longer than I expected, but it can get reasonable once you get the proper image (I took the one you sketched for the question).